# JS find and delete an object from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can i delete item that i have found ??

```
const item = array[index].items.find(item =>
            item.something === something
        );
        if(item){
            // delete here 
        }
```

Comment: Use filter instead of find

Comment: Do you want to delete full `item` object or `item.somethig` ?

Comment: @anttud Thanks!